# How to plot time series data with different categories in ggplot 2

Tags: r, ggplot2, time

This is the dataset

```
group <- c(1,2,3,1,2,3)
species <- c("rabbit","rabbit","rabbit","plant","plant","plant")
t1 <- c(66,77,80,4,3,1)
t2 <- c(4,5,22,1,2,6)
t100 <- c(56,78,22,1,6,7)
df <- data.frame(group, species,t1,t2,t100)
```

where ti represents time for the ith time-frame. In my original dataset I have 100 such columns.

I need to plot time series for the data such that rows with the same group number have the same colour lines, but different symbols (`pch`). Ideally, I need one symbol for the "rabbits" category, and another for "plants".

Here is my attempt

```
time <- c(1,2,100)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x = time, y=df[,3:5], colour = group)) #I don't know how to take it from here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that with few modifications of you `df`:

1. Melting your df by `group` and `species`

   library(reshape)
   df2=melt(df, id=c("group", "species"))
2. Define `group` column as factor:

`df2$group=as.factor(df2$group)`

And then the plot:

```
ggplot(df2, aes(x=variable, y=value, colour=group, shape = species, group=interaction(group, species))) + geom_point(size=3) + geom_line(size=1)
```

[image]